# Decoding Django session data in Node js

Tags: django, node.js, redis

I am trying to decode Django's session data stored in redis DB to JSON object. I have got session data from redis DB into a variable `djangoSessionData`, when in do console.log of this data, it looks like this:

```
���}    �(�_auth_user_backend��)django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend��_auth_us    er_hash_auth_user_id��2��user_unique_key��abc�u.65��
```

When I query redis directly and see session data value, it is like this:

```
"\x80\x04\x95\xaf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94(\x8c\x12_auth_user_backend\x94\x8c)django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend\x94\x8c\x0f_auth_user_hash\x94\x8c(6d34e7154c4d217233c7346177325969d1832565\x94\x8c\r_auth_user_id\x94\x8c\x012\x94\x8c\x0fuser_unique_key\x94\x8c\x03abc\x94u."
```

I am trying to decode it into JSON string using:

```
var sessionData = new Buffer(djangoSessionData, 'base64').toString();
```

But when I console.log `sessionData`, it looks like this:

```
������z��i���cjx(r���&ں�[i���
                         �ץ�$zwj�a����Z��߇�מ�ݵ�m�s���^��n}��u�}���ں��ǫ�'v�ǫ����翑��m˿
```

So looks like it is not decoding properly, how can it be decoded to JSON object in Node.js

Edit:
I am using Django 1.9 and saving session to redis DB using:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
```

Comment: Django sessions, I believe, are pickled by default. You can change that encoding to JSON instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229397/django-object-is-not-json-serializable-error-after-upgrading-django-to-1-6-5

Comment: @tsturzl with Django 1.6+ default session serializer is JSONSerializer. I also explicitly set it to JSONSerializer(`SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'`) but it doesn't make difference.

Comment: Seems that cache adaptor is still pickling the data. Someone forked the cache adaptor to add a JSON serializer, https://github.com/hellysmile/django-redis-sessions-fork