# Object of type User is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a an auto complete search for my web page and where I am trying to fetch name of users from database using ajax calls.

My AJAX call is running fine and going to designated URL.

I have tried using JSON encoder but that also did not work.

I am a bit new to DJANGO.Please help

My **views.py**

```
def autocomplete(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    q = request.GET.get('search', '').capitalize()
    search_qs = Profile.objects.filter(user__username__startswith=q)
    results = []
    print (q)
    for r in search_qs:
        results.append(r.user)
    data= json.dumps(list(results), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
else:
    data = 'fail'
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

My **models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**Error** I am getting

```
TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable
[] "GET /ajax_calls/search/?**term=he** HTTP/1.1" 500 15860
```

Comment: here is a link hope can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229397/django-object-is-not-json-serializable-error-after-upgrading-django-to-1-6-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are querying through `Profile`, where you can query directly through `User`. I think the proper implementation should be like this:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize 

users = User.objects.filter(username__startswith=q)

str_data = serialize('json', users, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder). # Or you don't need to provide the `cls` here because by default cls is DjangoJSONEncoder

data = json.loads(str_data)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) can be found here.

Comment: I wanted to ask one more thing that the query is returning every user in the database and not the just specific user that starts with **q** keyword.Am I doing something wrong with the queryset ?

Comment: Actually got it **term** was the query input and i was using **search** as the keyword.